# Possible Lost of Data Converting from size_t to int

Tags: c++, windows, type-conversion, desktop-application

Windows programming.  Following the tutorial at this [MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019) and get to this line at the bottom:

```
TextOutW(hdc, 5, 5, greeting, wcslen(greeting));
```

Variable `greeting` is a TCHAR array.  VS2019 reports a warning (C4267) at the above line that there is a possible loss of data in the final parameter converting from the <size_t> returned by wcslen() and the int expected by TextOutW().  I know that the original example uses the _tcslen macro instead of wcslen() - it doesn't matter.  I understand why that's happening but am completely mystified on how to modify the code to resolve the warning.

I can't find another TextOutx() that might take a <size_t>.

As an aside, while I was search for an answer, I read somewhere that strlen() is deprecated in 64-bit programming, although I can't recall where and I might have it wrong.

Is there a solution?  Any advice?

Comment: Unless you have strings literally billions of characters long this is just a warning. You can try and suppress it with casting.

Comment: `strlen()` can only deal with strings of length ~2.1 billion characters if your `size_t` is so limited. This wasn't really a problem on 32-bit architectures where you usually had a 4GB memory limit. Looks like [`strlen()` returns `size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) which should be sized according to architecture, unlike `int`, so there's no issue here with it being deprecated because of length limits, but `strnlen_s` is *safer*.

Comment: It's worth noting that calling `strlen()` on a >1GB string will be utterly excruciating from a performance perspective.

Comment: @tad You have identified the issue that isn't. This is a 64-bit build, where `wcslen` returns a 64 bits wide `size_t`. No issues there, at all. It's passing that value into `TextOutW` where the truncation to `int` happens.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm trying to explain why someone might have heard `strlen()` is "deprecated".

Comment: @tadman, as I retraced my steps, I believe it was PVS Studio that warned me of the use of strlen() in Win64 coding.

Comment: `strnlen_s` is a safer alternative as `strlen()` can overflow on corrupted data. Do you know the exact warning text?

Comment: First, the warning was "V303 The function 'lstrlen' is deprecated in the Win64 system. It is safer to use the 'wcslen' function."  But when I use wcslen() it generates the conversion warning.  Second, using lstrlenW() solves compiler conversion warning but PVS then reminds me that I should use wcslen().  Catch-22.  A explicit cast to `(int)wcslen(greeting);` resolves the warnings but hides the potential loss of data.  It's a moot point since the `greeting` string will never be _that_ lengthy.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @tadman, how do I upvote your original reply?

Comment: Doesn't really matter if you do, but if you want, the ^ type icon to the left does it. If that indicator is gone you may have already done it.

Comment: You may want to add a self-answer with the details you've found as you've done more research here than I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An explicit cast to `(int)wcslen(greeting);` resolves the warnings but hides the potential loss of data.